# What type of correlation should I choose in my BizTalk service?

Tags: xml, soap, biztalk, correlation, biztalk-orchestrations

[image: project orchestration image]

Task: BizTalk service should get message from client (Receive_1) and send it to remote 1cServise (Send_1). 
1cServise accepts messages, with such a structure:

empty POST request to address https://1Caddress.1cws

with Header - Content-type: text/xml

and Body - XML (plain text):

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                <soap:Body>
                    <m:Get xmlns:m="http://www.gis.com.ua">
                    </m:Get>
                </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Then 1cService returns message to BizTalk (Receive_2), and than - to client (Send_2).

My project will not compile until I add Correlation Property to messages Send_1 and Receive_2.

But what type of correlation property should I choose for sending right request to 1cService?
Or even, how to send correct message to 1cServise to get response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that in your case you have to use a solicit-response send port:

[image]

[image]

Because seems that in your case is invoke a service, that returns a response. You use a correlation, when you have some property or data to correlate the request and the response when the transport used is not synchronous, for example.

Comment: thanks for reply, I tried to use request-response first. But I got another error, because then request and response must correspond to one scheme. Request sheme is empty, but in response I get data in an unknown form. So BisTalk wrote error, that response message does not match the scheme.

Comment: @DmitriyBilberry  Why do they need to correspond to one schema?  That should not be the case usually

Comment: @DmitriyBilberry did yoy try using request-response with a generic "Any" type for the request-response messages? You don't need an schema

Comment: You have to assign to the Send Message and the Receive Message, Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.Any as Message Type